# Using perl to add up data in a csv file

Tags: perl

I need to write a Perl script to add all of the numbers in the following data. I need to use the built in <> function and split.

Right now all of the output I am getting is blank. Not sure how to fix it.

Sample data:

```
5,10,15,20,15,30
1,2,3,4,5
3,10
11
```

My written code

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum = 0;
my $filename = "data.csv";
open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die;
my @spl = split(/,/, $filename);


while (my $line = <$fh>) {
$sum += @spl;
}
print $sum;
```

The result should be 134

Comment: You are applying `split` over the filename, but you want to split the contents, right? Also, you are reading the contents into the `$line` variable, but then you are ignoring those contents...

Comment: @Poshi yes I am trying to split the contents. Would I change the while condition to be the split array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You try to `split` the filename, which doesn't make much sense here. You need to split each line from the file, so the splitting must happen in the loop in the `$line` variable.

When you actually split `$line`, you get a list of the numbers on that line. But then you have `sum += @spl;` and in scalar context, a list evaluates to the number of its elements, so you're counting, not summing, the numbers. Instead you need another loop over the split line to sum up the numbers.

I've placed the data in the `__DATA__` section of the script to simplify the code and avoid the file handling, but it works the same if you read from `<$fh>`.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum = 0;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    my @spl = split(/,/, $line);
    foreach my $num (@spl) {
        $sum += $num;
    }
}
print $sum;


__DATA__
5,10,15,20,15,30
1,2,3,4,5
3,10
11
```

This prints the expected 134.